# Trying to pass a CStringArray gives error cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, compiler-errors, cstring

I'm getting a strange error telling me that I cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject' when simply trying to pass a CStringArray to a function I have written to break it up into pieces.
I've commented out my entire function code so I know that the problem resides within the passing of the object itself, I'm assuming that I'm doing so incorrectly.

Here is my code:

```
    // If successful, read file into CStringArray
    CString strLine;
    CStringArray lines;
    while (theFile.ReadString(strLine))
    {
        lines.Add(strLine);
    }

    // Close the file, don't need it anymore
    theFile.Close();

    // Break up the string array and separate it into data
    CStringArrayHandler(lines);
```

Here is my CStringArrayHandler function:

```
void CSDI1View::CStringArrayHandler(CStringArray arr)
{
    // Left out code here since it is not the cause of the problem
}
```

Here is the declaration of the function in my header file:

```
class CSDI1View : public CView
{
// Operations
public:
    void CStringArrayHandler(CStringArray arr);   // <<<<===================
```

And here is the full text of the error I am getting:

> Error  1   error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class >'CObject' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxcoll.h 590 1   >SDI-1

Comment: Try passing the array to CStringArrayHandler by reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing `CStringArray arr` by value, so the copy constructor for `CStringArray` must be accessible. But it isn't, because `CStringArray` inherits from `CObject` which prohibits copying (that's what the compiler error message, which you actually didn't fully paste here, is saying)

The solution is to pass `arr` by reference:

```
void CStringArrayHandler(const CStringArray& arr);
```

Comment: The text of the error that I posted is all VS2013 gave me.  Thanks, I'll try this

Comment: @user134788 OK maybe, I don't have VS at hand, but I was under impression it should at least print the inaccessible constructor signature, that is `CObject(const CObject&)`

Comment: Though I wanted to actually operate on a CStringArray passed by reference. I cannot do it with const. Even tried using CArray<CString> seems to have the same problem. :(

Comment: @OzairKafray worth asking a new question perhaps?